# Marketing API - Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api, uipath

I POST an API request to generate Ad Report for an account using the endpoint

`https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/act_accountid/insights?time_range={'since':'2022-04-14','until':'2022-04-14'}&use_account_attribution_setting=true&use_unified_attribution_setting=true&time_increment=1&level=ad&fields=auction_bid,auction_competitiveness,body_asset,catalog_segment_actions,description_asset,device_platform,image_asset,impression_device,media_asset,title_asset,video_asset,activity_recency,ad_impression_actions,attribution_setting,adset_id,adset_name,impressions,clicks,spend,ad_id,ad_name,buying_type,reach,unique_clicks,frequency,video_play_actions,objective`

But the request is getting failed and showing a response like
`"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) body_asset, description_asset, device_platform, image_asset, impression_device, media_asset, title_asset, video_asset, activity_recency are not valid for fields param. please check https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/marketing-api\/reference\/ads-insights\/ for all valid values\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"AA1wnw3gU0iqCpMZrpTCAII\"}}"`

Anyone guide me how to get body_asset,description_asset, device_platform, image_asset, impression_device, media_asset, title_asset, video_asset?

**Adding details:**
To create an Ad Report, I POST a request in the following format.

`"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_############/insights?time_range={'since':'2022-05-14','until':'2022-05-14'}&time_increment=1&level=ad&fields=account_name,account_id,campaign_id,campaign_name,adset_id,adset_name,impressions,clicks,spend,ad_id,ad_name,buying_type,reach,unique_clicks,frequency,actions,video_30_sec_watched_actions,video_avg_time_watched_actions,video_p100_watched_actions,video_p25_watched_actions,video_p50_watched_actions,video_p75_watched_actions,video_p95_watched_actions,conversions,video_play_actions,objective,unique_video_continuous_2_sec_watched_actions,video_continuous_2_sec_watched_actions,cost_per_conversion,wish_bid&access_token=*********************************************"`

The response from this POST request gives me an **Ad Report ID**

Then, I use the Ad Report ID and get the required metrics from the response.

But, I can't able to get data for **Bid Type, Media Type, and Delivery**

[Ad Report FB - Delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVmSJ.png)[Ad Report FB - Media Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc8i6.png)[Ad Report FB - Bid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxQdq.png)

Thanks,

Comment: These are _breakdowns_, not fields. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns

Comment: But in API reference they mentioned this values in fields [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/insights/)

Comment: Then you should probably file a bug report and ask Facebook for clarification.

Comment: Is there a way to pull media asset type?

Comment: @cbroe As you said they are breakdowns. Then how can we include them in the report.

Comment: Breakdowns are not data to include, they specify what you want the data grouped by. You would pass them via the `breakdowns` parameter.

Comment: But while we give the breakdowns in Facebook Reporting, it fetches the data related to that breakdown value. Like, if I select delivery as a breakdown. The report downloaded from that has delivery status column.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass ACT_{ID_ACCOUNT} not act_accountid.
Should be replaced with the account id i guess.

Comment: I need to fetch the following columns from Facebook using API [Bid Type, Media Type, Delivery]. I can able to get Account ID, Account Name, Campaign Name, Campaign ID, Ad Set Name, Ad Set ID, Ad Name, Ad ID, Clicks, Impressions, Spend, Thruplay, Video Average Playtime, Video Play at 25%, 50%, 75%, 95%, and 100%. But, I can't able to get data for **Bid Type, Media Type and Delivery**